# Get equation of function given a sketch graph?

Tags: functions, curves, math-software

What's an example of a software tool that will let me sketch a graph and give me a possible equation of the graph?

Comment: How do you want to "sketch" it? Specify a list of points? I dont know of any that will let you *literally* sketch it on a drawing pad and spit out an equation, although many graphics tools do so implicitly...

Comment: @user3658307 yeah, the second way. To literally sketch it or put in an image.

Comment: so, the input would be an image? Would you label a $y$-axis and $x$-axis by hand as well? That sounds like a somewhat nasty [OCR problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). What is your *actual* goal (that you believe you need this tool for), overall?